# Horizontal layout of list items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, development, view

I have added a contact list to my team site (and I am showing only 2 fields; Name & Tele). Now I can control the  Number of items to display  inside the view, without any problem.

My question is if I can organize my list items in a horizontal way. For example, show 20 items in a column, then show another 20 items on a new horizontal column, something like this:

[image]

Comment: I had to do something similar, not sure if this makes sense for your case: http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Create a New Page with the 3 column page layout and put a ListView Webpart in each

Comment: but this will work if i have three different lists, but in my case i want the same list to be divided horizontal , instead of showing a paging links to show a new horizental column. now sure if this will work ..